# Use multiple branchs to deploy

Tags: google-app-engine, gcloud

I am testing the new google developer tools and it works really well.

I have the code in the master branch and when I commit and push the deploy is executed automatically. It works! But now I'm trying to use branches and keep each version of my GAE application in a branch and when I push that branch I get my version is deployed. But that's not working. Do you know it is supported? Do I need to configure something else to make it work?

If it only works with the master branch, it is ok. But it would be great to have it working with other branches as well.

Answer (score 3):

Sorry, the push to deploy hooks are only available on the master branch right now, but we'll definitely take note of this request.

Comment: Thank you for the feedback. I really think this feature is a key one for the development. Is there anyway I could implement it myself using git hooks?